# How to manage the scope and memory load heavy beans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Looks like I have a huge issue which is making me quite confused on how to fix it.

I am using 4.0.3.RELEASE of Spring and created an MVC rest application. Most of the configuration is done via Java config as wrote a class WebMVCConfig which extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

I have a spring bean that loads a text mining system which has some heavy lists. In a standalone application, I just load it once and everything I need to process some text I just call the process sentence method out of it. The constructor for that loads all lists once and after that it is just a matter of calling that function. The process function sometimes takes about 10 seconds, but sometimes it takes a few milliseconds to run all depends on the data.

Now, putting it on a Spring MVC application is interesting. If I set the scope to session scope for that bean: @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) it works just great, of course takes sometime to load on my rest application.

However, eventually it will run out of the memory as sessions are never killed right away.

If I do it on request it will be the same issue.

If I do it default application scope than I have an issue with concurrent usages of that bean. One user runs well, the other crashes.

I have no idea of what to do. Although session scope seems to be the correct answer to it as the state is preserved on each call. Not only the Bean is heavy but it can take 10 seconds sometimes to perform the analysis.

I have a Java Configuration class where I inject that bean into my Service Implementation class via @Inject annotation. Wonder if the correct would be @Autowire instead.

Basically I have my datamining Bean that is injected into my services bean via @Inject. I had assigned the 2 beans to be Session beans.

Wonder if I should assign the datamining Bean as session and the service bean as application and which method to use to wire that Datamining bean. Whether I use an @Autowire annotation or something else to avoid the problems I am having.

Also, what about ScopedProxyMode? Which one should be used on this case?

The situation, again, is a Heavy Bean which can have a slow processing time (10 seconds).

Thanks,